# Network support

Tags: gnosis-safe

How do i add support for new networks on my end?

As a non-developer, I did not really understand the instructions in this article (https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40795-supported-networks). I understand that after adding the support for the network, I will have to create the backend and frontend support as well.

But I think I need further clarification if there are more specific steps that are needed. Hope you guys could help me out!